# HTTPS connection to web server through SOAP::Lite in Perl

Tags: perl, web-services, soap, https

We have been using `SOAP::Lite` to consume web services in Perl over http connection. This has to be migrated to https connection.
I tried with ssl_opts with SSL_cert_file and SSL_key_file values in proxy().
I am getting a fatal relocation error as below:

> Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.so: symbol OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms: referenced symbol not found

Could you please help me resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From http://marc.info/?l=openssl-users&m=100632345124756&w=2

> Make sure that LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable contains the 
>   libraries for openssl.  Also, make sure any old openssl installation
>   libs are not in that path.

Comment: Thanks Rsadinha. The libraries are all in place. Just want to know, if the webserver, which provides the web service, should have to have any set up to authenticate the certificates?

Comment: Can anyone let me know, how do we check what version of libraries are compiled during the perl installation?